# Remove specific characters inside a url in php

Tags: php, replace

I need a php code that will be able to remove only a specific part of a url for ex this type of url:

http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/picture-242x300.jpg

To remove only the the first seven characters after the "-" and also to be removed "-"

So the final output would be 
http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/picture.jpg

Where the extension would be at the end .jpg, .gif or .png

The correct code is
$image = preg_replace("#-[0-9a-z]+.(jpe?g|gif|png)#i",".$1$2",$image);

Comment: "I need a php code that will be able to" --- that's easy - hire someone.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$url = preg_replace("#-[0-9a-z]+\.(jpe?g|gif|png)$#i","\\1",$url);
```

Take a look at the [preg_replace() documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Comment: Tnx for the update Jon after testing your code i am only getting
http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/picture
instead of the whole url
http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/picture.jpg
from the example that i've posted above

Comment: @user2934735 forgot a backref, see edit

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php
      $string='http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/picture-242x300.jpg';
      $s=preg_replace('/[-]\d*x\d*/','',$string);
      echo $s;
   ?>
```